# How can I debug php mounted to a container running on docker beta for mac

Tags: php, docker, xdebug

I have spent half the day trying different things including this solution I came across on [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/chadrien/c90927ec2d160ffea9c4)

I have a docker-compose file which mounts a folder containing my client and server projects:

```
 volumes:
    - ~/projectx:/projectx
```

my docker php.ini contains the following xdebug options

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 999
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 999
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 100
```

I have the xdebug [chrome extension](https://github.com/mac-cain13/xdebug-helper-for-chrome) installed

In my mac host file I have the following `127.0.0.1 localhost dtest.xxx.com` so I can access my web app (and other docker web apps) through `dtest.xxx.com` which all works to run the app

In Phpstorm (version 2016.1.2) In preferences `->` Languages & Frameworks `->` PHP `->` Servers I have :

host = dtest.xxx.com, port=80 , Debugger = Xdebug 
Use path mappings is checked and I have
      File/Directory set to `/Users/<myname>/projectx/server`
      Absolute path on the server is set to `/projectx/server`

I have tried setting the `xdebug.remote_host` to my macs ip obtained from ifconfig as well as trying the ip in `/Users/<myname>/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/slirp/host`

But I cannot hit a breakpoint , I have even added `xdebug_break()` double check.
I am also running the latest docker beta `Version 1.12.0-rc3-beta18 (build: 9996)`

I would very much appreciate anyone's help, it's a real blocker for me.

If any further information is required I am happy to provide.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## UPDATE 2:

As pointed out by @Rashidul , Since 17.06 docker for Mac, you can replace `xdebug.remote_host="192.168.65.1"` with `xdebug.remote_host="docker.for.mac.localhost"`

## UPDATE: <s>The Correct way</s>

so I eventually figured out that my xdebug settings in docker should be

```
xdebug.enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host="192.168.65.1"
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

where `192.168.65.1` is the entry found in  <s>`~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/slirp/host`</s>

In recent update the above no longer exists, to get the Docker host IP I know use the below my `.profile`

```
export DOCKER_HOST_IP=$(ipconfig getifaddr en0)
```

Also make sure to set the idekey correctly in the chrome extension, in my case `PHPSTORM`
With this I no longer require the ssh tunnel

### Original Solution:

The workaround I used was to open up an ssh tunnel to the docker container running php using a command like, in my case I have the docker container ssh port mapped to 12 hence the `-p 12`

```
ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 root@dtest.xxx.com -p:12
```

Comment: Does that still require the ssh tunnel ?

Comment: @Pilippe no it does not require the ssh tunnel

Comment: @jonnie The fact you showed where the host IP can be found resolved an issue I had with zend debugger being set within a docker beta container.
Thanks!

Comment: This also works for Windows! Besides that you get the remote host ip by opening the windows cmd and typing `ipconfig` (IPv4-Address of your network adapter). I don't know where `[...]/slirp/host` is located on Windows.

Comment: @PhilippMichael actually recently I had to change my approach to this too due to changes in Docker native (beta)

Comment: @jonnie, since 17.06 docker for mac, you can replace `xdebug.remote_host="192.168.65.1"` with `xdebug.remote_host="docker.for.mac.localhost"`

Comment: Been searching for hours, this is what worked for me. Thank you @jonnie